# Yii2 : Subdirectory in yii2 not working

Tags: yii2

I created a sub folder in yii2 installed project and I want to work this sub folder as a normal html website but its redirecting to yii2 login page. How to make it work as a normal html website?

Comment: This probably is webserver misconfiguration. Try configuring your webserver that existing files are served, but not existing are redirect to Yii, The configuration provided in the guide should do that: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html#configuring-web-servers

Comment: This folder should be in web directory then.

Answer (score 3):

In my eyes, you can think of your sub folder as a [module in yii2](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-modules.html), which can be accessed as a single section with a route like this:
 `[your root directory]/[your module name]/[your controller under the module]/[your action]`

Answer (score 2):

You can add it inside the `yii2app/frontend/web/` folder. Because this folder is public.

Rewrite the `url` if you want. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^desiredurl/$ frontend/web/subfolder/filename [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the Yii2 routing as well, make sure the application is allowing access to the html directory. Ideally you would put you HTML in the 'view' directory as per MVC/Yii2 design principles.

Answer (score 0):

For example you add normal_html folder in yii2 directory. You should edit web server's configuration (if it's nginx change root else if apache change DocumentRoot) folder.

Answer (score 0):

Create your subfolder with your HTML page within your `/web` folder. When your Yii2 Website is reachable via `http://localhost/` you're now able to call your HTML Website via `http://localhost/your-subfolder/your-html-file.html`.

Answer (score 0):

No need to create folder in web folder . You can just achieve this by creating a folder in your yii2 root directory but keep remember below things :

**1. Keep index.html/index.php in your sub folder.**

**2. Do not use subfolders in your subfolder.**

**3. Your subfolder files should not in format of yii2 url format.**